# Karnaugh map minimum sum of products

Tags: logic, algorithms

I'm trying to give the minimum sum of products using Karnaugh Map of this expression:

```
F = A’B’CD + AB’CD + A’BC’D + A’B’C’D + AB’C’D + ABC’D’ + A’BC’D’ + A’B’C’D’ + ABCD’ + A’BCD’
```

and this is what i've done:

[image]

and this is the result:

```
F = A’C’ + A’B’D + AB’D + BCD’ + BC’D’
```

but according to this thread:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21069300/the-result-of-the-logic-diagram/21069345?noredirect=1#21069345

the answer should be `F = AC+B’D+BD’`?

I'm confused!

EDITED:

[image]

Comment: Firstly, it's not okay to omit two of the $1$s like that.  Secondly, your two $2\times1$ circlings can be made bigger by wrapping around.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. How do you make them bigger by "wrapping around"?

Comment: I've edited the question, was that how it supposed to be?

Comment: Like in Pac-Man.

Comment: Like the one I've just edited? but how do I give the minimum sum of products?

Comment: The answer I've got now is: F = A’C’ + BD’ + B’D. Is that correct? I'm slightly confused!

Answer (score 0):

The left vertical edge forms a continuum with (wraps around to) the right vertical edge.
So, BCD' + BC'D' = BD'.

The top horizontal edge forms a continuum with (wraps around to) the bottom horizontal edge.
So, A'B'D + AB'D = B'D.

Bingo!